# How to assign different volume path to different replica of the same pod in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I need to create more than one replica of the same pod and during processing a file will be generated inside the pod. I want to have different volume path's for different replica's of the same pod .

Comment: Could you elaborate what you want to achieve? You want to use Deployment/Statefulset or you would like to use jobs? To clarify, you want to change path inside pod, and all replicas would be connected to one Volume? Scenario would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you did not specify what you exactly want to achieve and how.

If we would approach this from `Kubernetes Objects` with some controllers like [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) it will not be possible to achieve.
`Deployment` runs identical replicas of your desired configuration and you cannot adjust them to use different volume paths in some `pods`.

If you would just want to create a few pods with the same configuration but without controller you might use some kind of script or [Helm](https://helm.sh/). You would need to specify those parameters and `script/hel`m might create `pod` with different `volume path`.

Another thing you might consider for processing data is use [CronJobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/).

If you would want more precise answer please provide more information or use case how it should work.